# Listing all commit history on a deleted branch

Tags: git

I have deleted a remote branch on my project a few months ago but now I need to access it :(

The branch has been removed from both my local computer and from the remote git server.

How can I view the list of all commits on a deleted branch and then checkout (or merge) one of those commits to my local computer?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the branch has been merged back into the original branch, then you can still view all of the commits (but not necessarily as a separate branch).  Assuming the deleted branch has not been garbage collected, you could try to use `git reflog` to view the original checkout of the branch and then clone it: http://deekayen.net/recover-deleted-git-branch